# Code only returns if statement, ignores everything else

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I know this is simple but I can't get this code to work. No matter the order I put the variables or if/elif statements in, it only returns the if statement regardless of the month.

```
months = input("Enter a month to find out how many days are in that month, or enter 'exit' to quit the program\n")

months_28 = "February" 
months_30 = "April", "June", "September", "November" 
months_31 = "January", "March", "May", "July", "August", "October", "December"

if months or months.casefold() in months_28:
    print("There are 28 days in", months.capitalize()) 
elif months or months.casefold() in months_30:
    print("There are 30 days in", months.capitalize()) 
elif months or months.casefold() in months_31:
    print("There are 31 days in", months.capitalize()) 
else:
    print("That's not a month")
```

I also am trying to work a while loop into this too (as reflected in the beginning) and any help there would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you're trying to set months_* as lists,  you're doing it incorrectly.   should be ```months_31 = ["January", "March",...]``` etc.

Comment: `casefold` puts the string into lower case (among other things). The strings in your `months_` tuples are not in lower case, so the if statements will not match. Also your `months_28` is not a tuple like the others, it's just a string. It would make more sense to use sets.

Comment: put a comma after "February". Use .capitalize() instead of casefold().

Answer (score 1):

## You can Fabricate your code even more, with

1. Python's one of the strongest data structures - Dictionaries
2. Exception handling usage instead of if-else
3. F-strings, to increase readability of code

These Changes not only optimises your code, but also reduces time and space complexity

## I've recoded it for you --

```
months = input("Enter a month to find out how many days are in that month, or enter 'exit' to quit the program")

Month_Days = {
  'February': 28,
  'April': 30, 'June': 30, 'September': 30, 'November': 30,
  'January': 31, 'March': 31, 'May': 31, 'July': 31, 'August': 31, 'October': 31, 'December': 31
  }

try: print(f"There are {Month_Days[months.title()]} days in", months.capitalize()) 
except Exception: print("That's not a month")
```

With this, you not even have to add additional condition for exit, that'll be handled by try/except

Answer (score 0):

Your months_* need to be lists.

```
months = input("Enter a month to find out how many days are in that month, or enter 'exit' to quit the program\n")

months_28 = ["february"]
months_30 = ["april", "june", "september", "november"]
months_31 = ["january", "march", "may", "july", "august", "october", "december"]

if months and months.casefold() in months_28:
    print("There are 28 days in", months.capitalize()) 
elif months and months.casefold() in months_30:
    print("There are 30 days in", months.capitalize()) 
elif months and months.casefold() in months_31:
    print("There are 31 days in", months.capitalize()) 
else:
    print("That's not a month")
```

Just using your code with the minor changes.  There are obviously different ways of printing what you want out.

Comment: did you test the code? >>> months_30 = "April", "June", "September", "November" 
>>> months_30
('April', 'June', 'September', 'November')
>>> 'April' in months_30
True

Comment: This gives the same output as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes in your code:

- `months_28` is just a string. To convert that to a `tuple` add a `,` at the end
- Instead of using `casefold()`, I suggest using `title()` as the months names start with a Capital letter
- You must use `and` and not `or` in the `if` conditions because you want both the conditions to be `True`.

Below code will do what you require.

```
months = input("Enter a month to find out how many days are in that month, or enter 'exit' to quit the program\n")

months_28 = "February", 
months_30 = "April", "June", "September", "November" 
months_31 = "January", "March", "May", "July", "August", "October", "December"

if months and months.title() in months_28:
    print("There are 28 days in", months.capitalize()) 
elif months and months.title() in months_30:
    print("There are 30 days in", months.capitalize()) 
elif months and months.title() in months_31:
    print("There are 31 days in", months.capitalize()) 
else:
    print("That's not a month")
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your problem and adds the loop you need.

```
months_28 = ["February"]
months_30 = ["April", "June", "September", "November"] 
months_31 = ["January", "March", "May", "July", "August", "October", "December"]

another = True
while another:
    choice = input("[1] Enter a month to find out how many days are in that month\n[2] Enter 'exit' to quit\n")
    while True:
        if choice == '1':
            month = input("Enter month: ").capitalize().strip()
            if month in months_28:
                print("There are 28 days in", month)
            elif month in months_30:
                print("There are 30 days in", month)
            elif month in months_31:
                print("There are 31 days in", month)
            else:
                print("Invalid entry.")
        elif choice == '2':
            print('Buh bye!')
            break

        another = input("Try another month? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
        if another == 'Y':
            anpther = True
        elif another == 'N':
            print("Good bye!")
            break
    break
```